# Quadratic covariation of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X,Y \in \lambda^2_{loc}$ and let $M_t=\int_0^tX_sdB_s^i $ and $M_t=\int_0^tY_sdB_s^j$, with $i\neq j$.

With $B_s^i$ and $B_s^j$ I indicate the one dimensional B.M. of a $d$ dimensional B.M. $B=(B_t^1...B_t^d)$

How could I prove that $\langle M,N \rangle_t=0$?? I think I have to refer to the definition of the stochastic integral with simple process but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you say that it is zero?. You can see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811302/quadratic-covariation-of-two-it%C3%B4-processes

Comment: @UBM I modified the question. UBM glad to see you always available here in this forum :)

Comment: Pay attention: let $M_t=\int_0^tX_s^TdB_s$ and $N_t=\int_0^tY_s^TdB_s $ then $\langle M,N \rangle_t = \sum_{k=1}^{d}\int_0^tX_s^kY_s^kds$ where $X^T$ is a transpose vector and $B_s$ a d dimensional Brownian motion

Comment: as you can see M and N are a sum of stochastic integrals. and their quadratic covariation make sense only when i=j, in all the other case the quadratic covariation is 0. that's why the result with the summation that I wrote on the answer holds

Comment: M is the sum of stochastic integral is meant the M on my comment: $M_t=\int_0^tX_s^TdBs=\sum_{k=1}^d\int_0^tX_s^kdB_s^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, $B_s^i, B_s^j$ are independent $1$-dimensional Brownian motions. This implies that $[B_s^i, B_s^j]_t = 0$ (see the section on quadratic variation of B.M. [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/quadratic-variations-and-integration-by-parts/)).

The result now follows immediately since by standard properties of the Ito integral, we have that $[M,N]_t = \int_0^t M_s N_s d [ B^i, B^j]_s = 0$.

Comment: could you better explain which property are you applying? (anyway I wanted to prove the result without applying ito)

Comment: The property I am using is that $[ \int_0^\cdot F_s dX_s, Y]_t = \int_0^t F_s d[X,Y]_s$. This can be viewed as essentially the defining property of the Ito integral (in that it uniquely characterises $\int_0^\cdot F_s dX_s$) and doesn't rely on Ito's lemma. You will need to use a property like this since $M,N$ are defined as Ito integrals and so you'll need to use some property of Ito integrals to do this computation. You will see applications of this property of this type a lot in the subject so its worth getting used to it.