# prove that process $Z_t=(\int_0^tf(s)dW_s)-\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds$ is a local martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Hello i have 2 questions.

$1)$ I need to prove that if $X_t, Y_t$ - Ito processes, then

$X_tY_t=X_0Y_0+\int_0^tX_sdY_s+\int_0^tY_sdX_s+\int_0^tdX_sdY_s, t\ge 0$

it is enought to wright this like that? From Ito formula

$d(X_tY_t)=Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+\frac{1}{2}(dX_tdY_t+dY_tdX_t)=Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+dX_tdY_t$

so

$X_tY_t=X_0Y_0+\int_0^tX_sdY_s+\int_0^tY_sdX_s+\int_0^tdX_sdY_s$

Is it okay?

$2$. Using formula from point $1$ prove that process

$Z_t=(\int_0^tf(s)dW_s\int_0^tg(s)dW_s)-\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds$

is a local martingale for any $f,g\in P_{[0,T]}^2$ where

$P_{[0,T]}^2=\{X:\Omega\times[0,+\infty]: X - \text{adapted to }   (F_t), P(\int_0^T|X(t)|^2dt<+\infty)=1\}$

Comment: does anyone know how to show it

Comment: are you sure there's no mistake in point 2? because the first stochastic integral is a local martingale under your assumptions, but then we have the second term. In general an Ito process is a local martingale iff the drift is $0$

Comment: you're right, I rewrote the formula incorrectly, I corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_t=\int_0^t g(s)dW_s$ and $X_t=\int_0^t f(s)dW_s$, where $g$ and $f$ satisfy the condition you imposed, hence they ($X$ and $Y$) are continuous local martingales.

Then making use of the expression that you've obtain in the previous step

$$X_t Y_t=X_0Y_0+\int_0^tX_sdY_s+\int_0^tY_sdX_s+\int_0^tdX_sdY_s$$

you have that $$\int_0^tdX_s\cdot dY_s=\langle X,Y \rangle_t=\bigg\langle\left(\int_0^t g(s)dW_s\right),\left(\int_0^t f(s)dW_s\right)\bigg\rangle(t)=\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds$$

Hence your $(Z_t)$ is a process defined as

$$Z_t=\int_0^tX_sdY_s+\int_0^tY_sdX_s$$

You can now use some localizing sequence (of stopping times)

$$\tau_n=\inf\{t\geq 0: \int_0^t|X(s)|^2d\langle Y \rangle_s\geq n\}\wedge T$$
$$\sigma_n=\inf\{t\geq 0: \int_0^t|Y(s)|^2d\langle X \rangle_s\geq n\}\wedge T$$

Then we have

$$E\left(\int_0^{t\wedge\tau_n\wedge \sigma_n}X^2(s)d\langle Y\rangle_s\right)<\infty$$

Same holds for Y.

Hence $$Z_{t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n}=\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n} X_sdY_s+\int_0^ {t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n} Y_sdX_s$$
is a martingale, and this implies that $Z_t$ is a local martingale.

Comment: Can you explain this? $\int_0^tdX_s\cdot dY_s=\langle X,Y \rangle_t=\bigg\langle\left(\int_0^t g(s)dW_s\right),\left(\int_0^t f(s)dW_s\right)\bigg\rangle(t)=\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds$ what is this operation called?

Comment: It's simply the quadratic variation of two Ito processes, there's a very good answer in the site! Look for it!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811302/quadratic-covariation-of-two-it%C3%B4-processes

Comment: thanks, could you recommend some good books about stochastic processes, Ito integrals etc.?

Comment: Sure! I started with "Introduction to Stochastic Integration " by H. Kuo. It's a very nice book, very well written; the level is not that high, so you'll be able to read it without problems. If you are searching for something more advanced Karatzas  and Shreve is a must, even if it could be very complicated at times. Another great book is "Brownian Motion: an introduction to stochastic processes" by Rene Schilling and finally one of my personal favourites is "Stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes" by Ikeda and Watanabe.

Comment: Thanks again :) I can not only find "Brownian Motion: an introduction to stochastic processes" by Rene Schilling but the other three should be enough

Comment: Last question. Can you explain why $Z_{t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n}=\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n} X_sdY_s+\int_0^ {t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n} Y_sdX_s$ is a martignale?

Comment: because I understand that $X_{t\wedge \tau_n}$ is a martingale but why $\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n\wedge \sigma_n} X_sdY_s$ is a martingale?

Comment: notice that I've changed the localizing sequences. The (stopped) stochastic integral with respect to the martingale $Y$ is a martingale because $X$ is square integrable with respect to $P\otimes \langle Y \rangle \cdot \lambda$

Comment: "The (stopped) stochastic integral with respect to the martingale Y is a martingale because X is square integrable with respect to P⊗⟨Y⟩⋅λ "  Shouldn't be there "local martignale Y"? could you give some name for this claim or a source for it?

Comment: Yes it should be local martingale look the chapter 2 of Ikeda Watanabe when they define the stochastic integral with respect to local martingales

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong: If $X(t)$ such that $E\left(\int_0^{t\wedge\tau_n}X^2(s)d\langle Y\rangle_s\right)<\infty$ where $Y_s$ - local martingale, then $\int_0^tX_sdY_s$ is a local martingale? Then the same we can do with $Y_t$ and stopping times $\sigma_n$ so the $Z_t$ is a local martingale as the sum of two local martingales? I cant find this theorem "The (stopped) stochastic integral with respect to the martingale Y is a martingale because X is square integrable with respect to P⊗⟨Y⟩⋅λ " so that's all I came up with. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: I've just realised that the sequence of stopping times does not diverge a.s. I'll try to solve it asap